# JEST: My Isolated module function depends on a function found on the same module. After mocking, it still relies on the original implementation

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have

***abc.js***

```
const a = (a)=>{
    return (b(a) + 1)
}

const b = (num)=>{
    return(num + 1)
}

module.exports = {
    a,
    b
}
```

When I do my test for function a, I wanted a mock implementation of function b. but function a, after mocking, still has been using the original implementation instead of my mock.

my test looks something like

**abs.test.js**

```
const { a } = require('./abc')

describe('/abc functions',()=>{

    beforeEach(()=>{
        jest.mock('./abc',()=>(
       b = jest.fn.mockReturnValue(5)
     ))
    })

    afterEach(()=>{
        jest.clearAllMocks()
    })

    it('uses the b() mock',()=>{



        const aResult = a(1)
        expect(aResult).toBe(6)
    })

})
```

but I get a result of 2 or whatever the original implementation is.
I just wanted my function a to use my mock and it never does. it always goes back to the original implementation.

I tried jest.isolate() to isolate the function im testing.
I tried differernt ways of mocking like jest.fn(), jest.spyOn, and the method about jest.requireActual(moduleName)

I tried b = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>{})

I am confused as to why function a, even after Isolation, still relies on original implementation of function b...

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember the rules of lexical scoping and how that ties into the concept of closures. The short answer would be that the reason your test isn't working is because in your module `abc.js` your function `a()` calls inside its body the function `b()` that has been declared in that same module. The environment where the function was defined and NOT the one where it is called is what is called lexical scoping. This combination of the body of a function making use of the bindings where it was defined and the call of that function in the context of that those existing bindings/environment is what's called a closure. So, it doesn't matter if you mock a function `b()` and try to use that mock to alter the return value of `a()`, `a()` will always make use of the original function `b()` because that's the rules of lexical scoping dictate

Comment: I solved this by decoupling said functions even before i read your answer. No one answered my question so I initially gave the correct answer to myself. But I never really could point out "WHY" it happened. Until you mentioned closures. I understood lexical scoping and closure as a preparation for job interviews,but never really had a close encounter with in at work. (I'm a junior dev). Thank you for taking the time to answer as to WHY. There are so many HOW references out there but no WHYs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Different approaches to solving the problem.
one of it is to "modularize" these functions further by partitioning them into their own modules.
more information on this thread:
[github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936#issuecomment-545080082)